# Sharepoint 2010 - Ajax query only returning object but not value

Tags: 2010, jquery-ajax

I am using the following code, but all it is returning is "object object" when I need to return whats actually in the value of the column of the list for each list item. Any suggestions?

The list item I am trying to get is a lookup/dropdown value for the item in the list. I can get any other column data except this one.

```
            //start of jQuery document ready section
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                var basePath = "https://sp.test.com/ts/"; //This is your base site url with "/_api/" appended to the end
                var listName = "TestList"; //This is where you put the name of your picture library


                //start of Ajax query
                jQuery.ajax({
                //
                //This is where you add the fields you would like to return after the "select=". Separate fields by a ","
                url: basePath + "_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"+listName+"?$select=Region1", 
                //
                type: "GET", //This is set to GET so it can pull the data properly
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }, //This just sets the data to be returned as json data
                success: function (data) //data is a system variable which contains the data returned from the server
                {
                jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) 
                //index is the index of items
                //value is the item being receieved
                //data.d is the serialized data value from the query, and adding .results to the end gets the results of the serialized data
                {
                alert(value.Region1);
            alert(data.d.results);
                });
                },
                error: function (data) 
                {
                //Error gets output here
                alert(data.statusText); //data.statusText displays the status of the call
                },
                //
                complete: function()
                {
                //alert("ah!");
                //Insert any code here that you want to run when the ajax call has completed
                }
                });
                //End of Ajax query
                });
                //End of jQuery document ready section</script>
```

Comment: I needed to change the basePath portion that read "Region1" to "Region1&$expand=Region1" and then change the alert to read "value.Region1.Id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the basePath portion that read "Region1" to "Region1&$expand=Region1" and then change the alert to read "value.Region1.Id"

Correct Code:

```
            //start of jQuery document ready section
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                var basePath = "https://sp.test.com/ts/"; //This is your base site url with "/_api/" appended to the end
                var listName = "TestList"; //This is where you put the name of your picture library


                //start of Ajax query
                jQuery.ajax({
                //
                //This is where you add the fields you would like to return after the "select=". Separate fields by a ","
                url: basePath + "_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"+listName+"?$select=Name,Time1,Region1&$expand=Region1", 
                //
                type: "GET", //This is set to GET so it can pull the data properly
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }, //This just sets the data to be returned as json data
                success: function (data) //data is a system variable which contains the data returned from the server
                {
                jQuery.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) 
                //index is the index of items
                //value is the item being receieved
                //data.d is the serialized data value from the query, and adding .results to the end gets the results of the serialized data
                {
                alert(value.Name.toString());
            alert(value.Region1.Id);    
            });
                },
                error: function (data) 
                {
                //Error gets output here
                alert(data.statusText); //data.statusText displays the status of the call
                },
                //
                complete: function()
                {
                //alert("ah!");
                //Insert any code here that you want to run when the ajax call has completed
                }
                });
                //End of Ajax query
                });
                //End of jQuery document ready section</script>
```